# Golang switch for a types returning boolean values

Tags: go

I've the following function which w**orks OK**,
But I wonder if there is **cleaner** way to write it in Golang

the function get a flag and according to the value(string value) provide two Boolean response (and error)

```
func validate(flag string) (bool, bool, error) {
    switch true {
    case flag == "":
        return true, true, nil
    case flag == "types":
        return true, false, nil
    case flag == "ast":
        return false, true, nil
    }

    return false, false, errors.New("wrong order of arguments")
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `switch true` with expression cases that all test `flag`'s value instead of just doing a normal `switch flag` here?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/kmFkWz2hQAM

Comment: @mkopriva - please add it as answer :) thank you very much! i was a bit confused ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func validate(flag string) (bool, bool, error) {
    switch flag {
    case "":
        return true, true, nil
    case "types":
        return true, false, nil
    case "ast":
        return false, true, nil
    }

    return false, false, errors.New("wrong order of arguments")
}
```

Have a look at the [docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Expression_switches) for a fleshed out description of switch.